# PropTypes sempre dá erro não importa se o valor está correto

Tags: javascript, react

Estou usando o React (`16.11.0`) com PropTypes (`15.7.2`) e Hooks.

E eu tenho um componente que recebe um objeto com alguns dados do banco de dados. Testando os dados usando o `console.log`:

```
{ console.log('Carousel reciving: ', typeof informations, informations) }
```

Imprime a seguinte mensagem:

```
Carousel reciving:  object (12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Os dados são enviados ao componente pela chamada:

```
<Carousel informations={informations} isLoading={isLoading} />
```

Componente:

```
const Carousel = ({ informations, isLoading }) => (
    <ReactPlaceholder ...algumas props />...algum contúdo</ReactPlaceholder>
) // Carousel
```

Mas não importa se eu altero o PropType para vetor ou objeto, continua dando o seguinte erro:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `informations` of type `array` supplied to `Carousel`, expected `object`.

Se eu mudar para `PropType.object.isRequired`, o erro diz que o valor fornecido é do tipo array. E se eu mudar para `PropType.array.isRequired`, o erro diz que o valor fornecido é do tipo objeto:

```
Carousel.propTypes = {
    informations: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
} // propTypes
```

Eu sei que poderia usar a função de `fetch` dentro do componente, mas esses dados são compartilhados com outros componentes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apesar de que,  no JavaScript, o tipo de um array é objeto, o PropTypes não considera um array como um objeto.

Demonstração:

```js
console.log(typeof {});
console.log(typeof []);
```

No seu caso, parece que você está passando um **array de objetos** para a propriedade `informations`. Então, no seu `PropTypes`, você deve declarar que quer validar um array de objetos.

Assim:

```js
Carousel.propTypes = {
  //                      ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓           ↓↓↓↓↓↓
  informations: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
  // Outras propriedades...
}
```

Adicionei uma [demonstração no CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-para-stackoverflow-em-portugues-8ygvy).